# Safari's issue with rendering inline-blocks scaled by scaleX

Tags: css, safari

This is the image of mug preview:

[image]

Preview displays what other div contains, but scaled down by 0.2. To simulate the mug's surface curve, I used a technique where preview blocks have width = orginal-width*0.2, and they are scaled by `scaleX` transform, by 0.6, 0.8, 1 , 0.8. 0.6.

It works fine (I can't use html5 canvas because of crossbrowser compatibility, it's a requirement), but, as you can see on attached image (top image is from chrome, bottom from safari), safari renders unwanted light lines. Nothing helps - absolute positioning, placing one block on other to hide that light line. It's issue specific to safari, it's probably because after `transformX` ledges of block are antialiased, and because of `scaleX`, the side ledges become more bright. Other browsers don't do that.

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix this to render without those lines in safari?

Comment: An illustration is good, but could you create a jsfiddle with your CSS markup so we can reproduce this in the different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size` instead of `transform: scale`.

Comment: I don't think it will solve my problem - the entire area with content must be sized proportionally, not only background. Maybe it's not clear at this image, but, those canvases can be filled with objects like text or images, and if i will start using background-size on every object, and rescalling manually text with font-size, I made unmanageable mess.. thats it why it must be done by scale on parent container.

Comment: You are quite right it would probably only be a solution if you do not need text.

One possible (but complicated) workaround could be to render the text and image on a canvas, export that as a data:URI that you set as the background-image.

Comment: so mabye that's the solution. Use what I got now as backward compatibility with IE8, and implement a new one preview on HTML5 canvas for modern browsers including safari